# Azure function naming standard

Tags: azure, spring-boot, azure-functions, azure-function-app, azure-functions-core-tools

I want to use single azure function name but for each function the http operations will be different, is it possible ?

For example -

```
 @FunctionName("message")
    public ResponseDTO saveMessage(
            @HttpTrigger(name = "messageReq", methods = {HttpMethod.POST}, authLevel = AuthorizationLevel.ANONYMOUS) HttpRequestMessage<Optional<Message>> request,
            ExecutionContext context) {
        return handleRequest(request.getBody().get(), context);
    }

@FunctionName("message")
    public ResponseDTO getMessage(
            @HttpTrigger(name = "MessageGetReq", methods = {HttpMethod.GET}, authLevel = AuthorizationLevel.ANONYMOUS) HttpRequestMessage request,
            @BindingName("to") String to, ExecutionContext context) {
        return handleRequest(to, context);
    }

@FunctionName("message")
    public ResponseDTO deleteMessage(
            @HttpTrigger(name = "MessageGetReq", methods = {HttpMethod.DELETE}, authLevel = AuthorizationLevel.ANONYMOUS) HttpRequestMessage request,
            @BindingName("id") String id, ExecutionContext context) {
        return handleRequest(id, context);
    }
```

I tried the same but don't know how to handle in bean file as @Bean name should match with Function name but in this case all bean name will be same as 'message' which will throw an error , even if we don't define bean name it will match with method name but for that also all 3 method name will be 'message' which will give compilation error.

```
@Bean("message")
    public Function<Message,ResponseDTO> saveMessage() {
        return message -> {
            return msgService.saveMessage(message);
        };
    }

    @Bean("message")
    public Function<String, ResponseDTO> deleteMessage() {
        return id -> msgService.getMessages1(id);
    }

    @Bean("message")
    public Function<String, ResponseDTO> getMessage() {
        return to -> msgService.getMessages1(to);
    }
```

In that way I want to have only one azure function name as 'message' with GET/POST/DELETE operation. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

are you able to do it by specifying the same route on each function - the name is then disregarded as it should go via route and then determine the function based on action.

e.g. route = /api/message